# Which link is there between Calculus and Quadrature?

Tags: calculus, integration, math-history

I'm trying to find the origin of the integration process. To do that I'm studying "De Analysi" by Newton. I would like to know the process that lead Newton to the Rule I $\ref{Rule I}$ below, and if it is linked with the quadrature problem.

[image: Analysis Per Quantitatum Series, Fluxiones, Ac Differentias:Cum Enumeratione Linearum Tertii Ordinis (Google eBook) p.1]

This is the first page of the original [book digitalized by Google](http://google.it/books?id=VTgPAAAAQAAJ&hl=it). The latin is quite simple this is a "user friendly" translation:

> General method to measure the "quantity" [area] of a curve by a series of infinte terms that I've found once, you [will] have it demonstrate in the following short explainations rather than an accurate demostration.
>
> Draw $BD$ perpendicular to the base $AB$ of the $AD$ curve: we call $AB=x$, $BD=y$.  $a,b,c,e$ are note quantities and $m,n$ integer. Then:

Here comes the question:

> Curvarum Simplicium Quadratura

In latin means "the quadature of a simple curve" and then Newton doesn't explain how he founds the classic rule, but simply explains that works.

$y=ax^{m/n};$ it shall be $(\frac{an}{m+n})x^{\frac{m+n}{n}} =$Area ABD $\tag{Rule I}$

Quadrature was a well know ancient Greek problem to build a square with the same area of another shape. The first thing I thought is to compare the area of a quarter of circle to the integration of the equation of the curve related but I'm not sure is right. Anybody has already faced this problem?

Comment: It is not clear to me what question you are asking (but I like the initials).

Comment: Classically "quadrature" is not a specific _method_, but merely a name for the _problem_ of finding a square with the same area as a given shape. The word doesn't imply anything about _how_ one solves that problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you're right I've corrected my error! I was projecting my brain to use it as a method to solve the problem. But if he uses this term which is the second "given shape" for Newton?

Comment: "I've tried to improve the answer." The answer? Anyway, I can think of two ways Newton might have figured out that the area under $ax^{m/n}$ is $(an/(m+n))x^{(m+n)/n}$. He might have done it by working out the derivative of $x^r$, and then applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Or he might have set up what we now call "Riemann sums" for the integral, as I believe Archimedes did for $y=x^2$.

Comment: Several people before Newton knew this. Fermat had a proof. Wallis had a heuristic argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks a lot!Can you be more precise?

Comment: It would take quite a long answer to describe in details the Fermat Method. Roughly speaking, he used a Riemann sum argument, with subdivision points an infinite geometric series with common ratio $r$, and then he let $r$ approach $1$. It was done well before Newton. And it would not answer your question about Newton.